# Monotone class-style theorem

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, monotone-class-theorem

I've seen people using arguments along the lines of the following one, but never a proof or a detailed statement.
Can anyone help me find one?

> Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector space of bounded functions $X\to\Bbb{R}$ containing $1$, and suppose that it is closed under products and monotone limits.
> Let $\Sigma$ be the collection of all subsets $E$ of $X$ such that the indicator function $1_E$ is in $\mathcal{E}$.
> Then $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, and every function in $\mathcal{E}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.

First of all, is the statement correct to begin with?

I can see why we have a $\sigma$-algebra.
For the rest, I feel like the Weierstrass approximation theorem should help, but I'm stuck.

(A reference would be welcome too, especially if this statement, or a closely related one, has a name.)

**Note**: this is *not* the usual monotone class theorem/pi-lambda theorem. We are asking whether every function in $\mathcal{E}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable, not if every $\Sigma$-measurable is in $\mathcal{E}$. (That's why we require that $\mathcal{E}$ is closed under products.)

Comment: I think we cannot use Weierstrass.  The functions are not continuous, and indeed $X$ is not a topological space.

Comment: If $f \in \mathcal E$, then $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.  Hint.  Start with a real number $t$.  We want to reach the indicator of the set $\{x : f(x) > t\}$ starting with $f$, with $1$, and using vector operations, products, monotone limits.

Comment: See here for a similar statement, with reference for a proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47521/151552

Comment: @PhoemueX It is not quite that. See the edit.